# Serialize Python code object (from compile())

Tags: python, compilation

After creating a Python code object via

```py
code = """a = 5
a += 6
print(a)
"""

obj = compile(code, "foobar.py", "exec")
print(obj)
```

```
<code object <module> at 0x7f6bef0ea190, file "foobar.py", line 1>
```

I would like to store that object in a string or file such that I can later construct the obj from the file again. (I do not want to store the plain string.)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same task.

You can use `marshal`, with the usual warning and some other limitations listed in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html):

> **Warning** The marshal module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unmarshal data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

Storing to file:

```
import marshal

with open("foobar.pyc", "wb") as f:
    marshal.dump(obj, f)
with open("foobar.pyc", "rb") as f:
    obj_restored = marshal.load(f)

print(obj_restored == obj)
```

Saving as string:

```
import base64
import marshal

serialized = marshal.dumps(obj)
obj_bytes = base64.b64encode(serialized)  # b64 bytes
obj_ascii_str = obj_bytes.decode("ascii")  # b64 string for json

restored_serialized = base64.b64decode(obj_ascii_str)
obj_restored = marshal.loads(restored_serialized)
print(obj_restored == obj)
```